# I want to communicate with google play store to get the details of users who are already purchased a subscription of my app by in app purchase

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, subscription, in-app-subscription

I have no detail stored of previous purchase on my server side like purchase id or purchase token, how can it be possible to get details of already purchase subscription without purchase id and token.

I want to communicate with google play store to get the details of users who are already purchased a subscription of my app by in app purchase when they cancel their subscription from play store and when the payment auto-renew or not

Comment: Do you want to query for users in your app? I can provide you a library link, where you can handle this